# Triple Boot Question

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-7, windows-8, dual-boot

I have successfully set up a a win7,win8 and Ubuntu 12.10 system. Windows 8 and Ubuntu are located on the same SSD, while windows 7 is located on another SSD. All went great and I can continue playing around with all 3 OS's. My only annoyance is, while restarting, windows 7 boot loader runs first. If I select ubuntu in the win7 manager it then runs grub2 and asks me to select an os. I used easy bcd to add entries into win8's boot manager and was hoping to just use that one. I installed ubuntu's loader on to its own partition. Any suggestions to just use Win8 loader and still be able to choose between all 3?

Comment: I haven't installed win8 yet, but isn't it possible to use just grub to select your OS?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out myself. The problem was in settings for easybcd and grub. I achieved my goal by "hiding" the grub boot menu from within Ubuntu. Also, when editing entries in easybcd, I checked the "skip boot menu" option. I restarted and it booted straight to the pretty blue Win 8 boot menu.